# Exception in StreamWriter and writing to a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, streamwriter

I'm trying to write a simple text file writer.

If I throw an exception in the using of the writer does it automatically close?

Is it OK to write it like this as it works and its only three lines. If the file is not there then it adds it and writes text into it; if it does exist then it appends text to it?

All the other example I have found online are way too long and complicated?

```
Try
    For index = 1 To 100 Step 1

        Dim filePath As String = "c:\TextFile2.txt"

        Using writer As New StreamWriter(filePath, True)
            writer.WriteLine("Important data line" & index)

            ''Throw New ArgumentException("Exception Occured")

        End Using
    Next

Catch ex As Exception

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

"using" is essentially a wrapping for a try/finally and dispose will be called as expected.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
WebClient c=new WebClient();
c.Disposed+= (sender, args) => {Console.WriteLine("DISPOSED");};
    using(c){
    throw new Exception("testing dispose");
    }
```